# How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu and python.  When I run the command LD_LIBRARY_PATH  , function works well.

```
***sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/binaries/linux/x86_64 \
python3 /recognizer/main.py***
```

above works well. But when typing only `python3 /recognizer/main.py` , does not work. I want to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add the following line to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/binaries/linux/x86_64"
```

The file is loaded every time you open a terminal. If you want to set the variable once when you login, add the line to ~/.profile instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can add that path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (with `sudo`), or to a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` (if that directory exists).
The second method has the advantage of being more organized compared to putting everything in one file.

After that, run `sudo ldconfig`. And then that library path will be added permanently for all users.

Example:

```bash
# As root
echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/onevpl.conf
echo "/usr/local/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/onevpl.conf
echo "/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/onevpl.conf
ldconfig
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line in your .bashrc which can be found in home directory

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/binaries/linux/x86_64
```

Comment: @KamalMahendraSirisena. Try re-opening the terminal and see if it works.